# Adding bibliographic references to a Google Docs document?

Tags: google-drive

How can I add my bibliographic references to a Google Docs document?

I've googled around for an answer and found [WizCiteWeb](http://help.wizfolio.com/Download.aspx?ver=wizciteweb) from WizFolio, but they [say](http://help.wizfolio.com/Contents/WizCite.aspx?gdocs=1) it only works with the older version of Google Docs and I can't seem to find any way to move back to the older version of Google docs. Any ideas?

Answer (score 15):

Google Docs now has built-in citation, using the research tool.

> The Research tool makes it easy to add information from the web to your documents and presentations. To access the tool:
>
> - Select the Research option from the Tools menu.
> - Use the keyboard shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> on Mac, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> on [PC](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/179738?hl=en)).
> - Right-click on a specific word and select Research.
> - Choose scholar in the search bar; search for your citation, and click on "Cite as Footnote".

[Source](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2481802).   **EDIT: THIS IS NOW BROKEN. [SOURCE](https://support.google.com/docs/forum/AAAABuH1jm0tqHYZHX-mAI?hl=en)**

EDIT

I have been made aware of a third-party add-on that provides more extensive citation functionality to Google Docs called [Paperpile](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/paperpile/imanmdcibgaflfaibbcmmkifdgllfopm).  It provides many different inline and footnoted citation styles (They claim >7000).

Also, Faculty of 1000 Workspace (http://f1000.com/work/; geared at life sciences) has a google docs [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/f1000/daojhpgpccggokldfgfdmeckecckheej) (http://f1000.com/work/faq/google-docs-add-on)

Comment: This is a great addition to Google Docs. Thanks.

Comment: But this is completely inappropriate for academic writing, where citations are done in particular formats (e.g. (Harvard, 1995) or IEEE [3]) and references are stored in a bibliography section at the end. Citing as footnotes is generally not acceptable in university papers, or journal and conference papers.

Comment: [As of December 5, 2016, the research tool is now working again.](http://i.imgur.com/LHzcqvy.png)

Comment: have you tried citing an academic article with the tool?  it doesn't work...

Comment: @Rikki, have you found a way to add the bibliography to the end of the document?

Comment: @SaqibAli Unfortunately not. I don't do much academic writing these days, and I definitely wouldn't use Google Docs, other than for an early draft.

Answer (score 8):

These three options could be useful to you:

1. [You can use Zotero with Google Docs, making footnotes or in-text citations and bibliographies!](https://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google%20Docs/thread?tid=36c53a120288d773&hl=en)
2. [Citing With URIs in Google Docs](http://hublog.hubmed.org/archives/001946.html)
3. [3 quick ways to use Mendeley for citations anywhere](http://www.mendeley.com/blog/tipstricks/3-quick-ways-to-use-mendeley-for-citations-anywhere/)

Comment: #1 now notes that there is Google Doc "add-on" called EasyBib, which might do the job!

Answer (score 2):

We've built Paperpile to solve this problem: https://paperpile.com

Here is a detailed guide how to add citations and format a bibliography in Google docs:

https://paperpile.com/help#guide-gdocs

Answer (score 1):

Comparable to Paperpile, COLWIZ https://www.colwiz.com/ provides wonderful integration of a citation manager and Google Docs. Check this one out. It is completeley free (still) while Paperpile is a paid service.

Answer (score 0):

The process for adding bibliographic data is

1. (Enter the references into the reference management of your choice.)
2. For every title you want to cite, insert the corresponding
   placeholder string into the Google Docs document. An example for
   such a placeholder would be {Baeza-Yates 1997 #3}. The reference
   management software will usually allow to copy the placeholder
   string for a chosen title to clipboard.
3. With all the placeholders entered into the document, export it as
   .rtf file.
4. Feed the .rtf file into the reference management software. Out will
   come a .rtf file with all the placeholders replaced by citations (in
   the style chosen) and a trailing list of citations.

... or use [WizFolio](http://www.youtube.com/user/wizfolio) web service (http://wizfolio.com/)

Comment: Apparently, WizFolio used to work on the older version of Google Docs (mid 2010) but not on the new one, which is the only one available right now. It would be great to see this tool updated!

Answer (score 0):

- **CTRL-ALT-F** and a new super script number will be created and the same number will appear in the footer, you can add a link or whatever you want over there.
- You can also do this graphically, **INSERT->FOOTNOTE**.