# Creating bibliographic "Works Cited" page in Google Docs

Tags: google-docs

[A previous question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/20878/adding-bibliographic-references-to-a-google-docs-document) asked how to add citations in Google Docs. The proposed solution was to use the built in **Research Tool** under `Tools → Explore`.

[image: citation footnotes]

Unfortunately, the research tool adds citations to the bottom of each page, rather than making a proper MLA "Works Cited" page.

[image: Works cited page]

**How can I create a single Works Cited page in Google Docs? Is there a script or addon I can use?**